# Zenit Launch Costs

Tags: rockets, cost, russia

I am compiling a table of data on price-mass ratios of various modern rockets, and I have been unable to find any information on how much it costs to launch a Zenit rocket. Does anybody know how much it costs to launch a Zenit rocket of any kind?

Comment: Zenit-2 from USSR time and Zenit 3SL from Sea Launch costs very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [slide](http://www.dglr.de/fileadmin/inhalte/dglr/fb/r1/r1_2/06-Raumtransportsysteme-Kosten.pdf#page=6) from DGLR, which is the non-profit space community of Germany, can help you further. What you want can be found in page 6. For the exact number you can contact the authors. They will definitely give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

> "The launch of one satellite is 250 million rubles [\$4mn], plus 70 million [\$1.1mn] for the launch itself. That [comes to] 320 million [\$5mn] - this is one [launch]. If we want to launch five satellites per year - it will be 1.6 billion [\$25mn] per year," Filev said.

<sup>([Russia's S7 plans for Sea Launch revealed to be a new $5mn rocket — Sott.net](https://www.sott.net/article/329771-Russias-S7-plans-for-Sea-Launch-revealed-to-be-a-new-5mn-rocket))</sup>

Vladislav Filev is the Chief Executive Officer of the S-7 Group--the owner of the former SeaLaunch/Landlaunch company (jointly owned by Boeing, RSC ENERGIA, YUZHNOYE and the Norwegian company, AKER CRUSADER).

----the follow-up for even cheaper and more accessible launch costs, will hinge on whether or not Zenit 3SL evolves and/or adapts printable engines.   Such a low-cost (cost per kg) may lead to the launching of asteroid recovery and mining much more quickly than many critics and analysts within the aerospace community had predicted or envisioned

Comment: Stackexchanged uses MathJax to display math symbols. The dollar sign is used to start an equation, this screwed up your formatting .I've added a backslash before each dollar sign to fix it.